# Issue in displaying p:messages for converterMessage

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message

I am using PrimeFaces but I have problem with display `<p:messages>` for converterMessage.
When I use JSF tag `<h:message>`, it works correctly or even when I insert it into columns, but when I change to `<p:message>` it does not show. Can anybody helps me? My page is:

```
<h:form id="form2" prependId="false"  style="direction:rtl;width: 600;top: 300px ;position: absolute" >

    <p:messages  for="count"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="sum credit :#{shoppingBean.sumcredit}"/><br/>
    <p:outputLabel value="shopping list :"/>

    <p:dataTable id="dataTbl2" var="selectedProduct" value="#{shoppingBean.selectedProduct}"  emptyMessage="no data"
                 paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" selection="#{shoppingBean.selection2}"
                 rowKey="#{selectedProduct.id}" disabledSelection="false" rows="5" paginator="true" pageLinks="5">

        <p:column style="color: blue">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="brand" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{selectedProduct.tblShopProduct.brand}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="price" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{selectedProduct.tblShopProduct.price}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue"  >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="date" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{shoppingBean.tblShopOrder.created.toString().substring(0,11)}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{shoppingBean.tblShopOrder.created.toString().substring(11,19)}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="number" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{selectedProduct.number}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="amount" />

            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{selectedProduct.amount}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText  value="edit"/>**<h:inputText  id="count" converterMessage="you allowed only for using number value="#{shoppingBean.count}"/>**
            </f:facet>

            <h:commandButton value="sum"  rendered="#{selectedProduct.number==null}"  action="#{shoppingBean.addProductCount(selectedProduct)}" />
            <h:commandButton value="confirm" disabled="true" rendered="#{selectedProduct.number!=null}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="color: blue" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="delete" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{shoppingBean.deleteBuyed(selectedProduct)}" />
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:commandButton value="final shopping" action="#{shoppingBean.finalShop(selectedProduct)}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Tohid Makari.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:outputText  value="edit"/>**<h:inputText  id="count" converterMessage="you allowed only for using number value="#{shoppingBean.count}"/>**
```

This line could not work. Fix this first.

You do not update your messages tag. 
Try something like this :

```
<p:messages for="count" autoUpdate="true" />
```